# Problem with flooding menu (php,javascript,ajax)?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have two drop down menus on my website.
Technologies used are Javascipt , php , mysql.

```
City : [        ] 
Area : [        ]
```

TODO:
When user selects city I want to query database for areas in city and dynamically populate the area drop down menu.

When user selects area I want to query database again for results that belong to that perticular area and city.

Somthing like this(step by step).

```
------------------------1
City:[Choose City]
------------------------2
City :[New York]
------------------------3
City :[New York] 
Area : [Choose Area]
------------------------4
City :[New York] 
Area : [Times Square]
    ------------------------4

10 Results Found for New York/Times Square:
1 . Result1 .
2 . Result2
...
..
.
```

Here is database schema:

```
CREATE DATABASE `db_results` ;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_results`(
    `result_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `result_title` VARCHAR(20),
    `result_content` TEXT,
    `result_category` INT,
    `result_city` INT,
    `result_area` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`result_id`),
);


CREATE TABLE `tbl_area`(
    `area_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `area_name` VARCHAR(50),
    `area_city` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`area_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `tbl_cities`(
    `city_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `city_name` VARCHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY(`city_id`)
);
```

I have created script to dynamically flood the menu but when I query database using dynamically generated menu it gives error that 'area' is undefined index.

Here is link to the files:
**[FILES](http://webwonderland.googlepages.com/problem4)**

Comment: I think that in order to get assistance here, you need to provide much more detail / sample code and highlight the exact issue you are experiencing.

Comment: I have created script to dynamically flood the menu but when I query database using dynamically generated menu it gives error that 
'area' is undefined index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much information to go on, but from your php error notice, you are trying to access an index in your results array / database table that does not exist (from your tbl_area definition - and assuming your query returns all fields - area_id, area_name and area_city are all valid indecies, but 'area' is not).

Comment: @BrynJ
I have provided link to files used. Take a look.